# Для чего нужен пустой конструктор в базовом классе?

Tags: c#, ооп, конструктор

Пишу проект по ООП.
У меня есть базовый класс `Order`. Создала производный класс `Request`.
У каждого из этих классов есть свой конструктор с параметрами. Только мне пришлось создать пустой конструктор в классе `Order`, иначе выводится ошибка:

```
CS1729 --- 'Order" не содержит конструктор, который принимает аргументы 0
```

Почему так происходит и для чего нужен пустой конструктор в этом случае?

Comment: Не нужен, если в наследнике указать конкретный конструктор базового класса

Comment: Например `public Request(string arg) : base(arg) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, производный класс неявно вызывает конструктор по умолчанию базового класса, особенно если он не имеет явного вызова конструктора базового класса.
Если базовый класс не содержит конструктора без параметров, то это вызовет ошибку компиляции, поскольку производный класс неявно обращается к конструктору по умолчанию базового класса, которого фактически нет.

Вот пример кода, иллюстрирующий неявный вызов конструктора по умолчанию базового класса из производного класса:

```cs
using System;

class Order {
    // Конструктор с параметром
    public Order(string orderId) {
        Console.WriteLine("Конструктор Order вызван с параметром orderId: " + orderId);
    }
}

class Request : Order {
    // Конструктор класса Request без явного вызова конструктора базового класса
    public Request() { // Здесь неявно вызывается конструктор по умолчанию базового класса Order
        Console.WriteLine("Конструктор Request");
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        // Этот код вызовет ошибку компиляции, так как базовый класс Order не имеет конструктора по умолчанию
        Request request = new Request();
    }
}
```

Варианты решения проблемы:

1. Определение конструктора по умолчанию в базовом классе `Order`:

```cs
using System;

class Order {
    // Пустой конструктор по умолчанию
    public Order() {
        Console.WriteLine("Конструктор Order без параметров");
    }
    // Конструктор с параметром
    public Order(string orderId) {
        Console.WriteLine("Конструктор Order вызван с параметром orderId: " + orderId);
    }
}

class Request : Order {
    // Конструктор класса Request без явного вызова конструктора базового класса
    public Request() {
        Console.WriteLine("Конструктор Request");
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        // Этот код успешно создаст объект класса Request, используя пустой конструктор базового класса
        Request request = new Request();
    }
}
```

2. Вызов конструктора `Order(string orderId)` в `Request`:

```cs
using System;

class Order {
    // Конструктор с параметром
    public Order(string orderId) {
        Console.WriteLine("Конструктор Order вызван с параметром orderId: " + orderId);
    }
}

class Request : Order {
    // Конструктор класса Request вызывает конструктор базового класса с параметром
    public Request() : base("someId") { // Вызов конструктора базового класса с параметром 
        Console.WriteLine("Конструктор Request");
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        // Этот код успешно создаст объект класса Request, используя конструктор базового класса с параметром
        Request request = new Request();
    }
}
```